# sudo kill results in permission denied

Tags: ubuntu

ps -aux | grep node results in:

```
root      2814  0.0  0.0   4344     0 ?        S    Mai27   0:00 sh -c node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
root      2815  0.0  0.0 1358316 1096 ?        Sl   Mai27   0:17 node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
root      2881  0.0  0.0   4344     0 ?        S    Mai27   0:00 sh -c npx webpack --mode development && node ./build/bundle.js
root      2910  0.0  0.7 1262156 63004 ?       Sl   Mai27   0:47 node ./build/bundle.js
```

`sudo kill 2814 2815 1881 2910` results in permission denied.

I understand that if you run it without `sudo` that permission denied makes sense if the user is not the one you executed the task with. However, here I have no clue and can someone explain why sometimes a root process cannot be killed with `sudo`? Does it make any sense? (Especially, because it is just a webpack process of my own project, I don't get it.)

Answer (score 7):

Since you are on Linux (Ubuntu) -- if `sudo kill` still gives `permission denied` then it could be because you're running inside a containerized application (e.g. Snap app) such as VSCode's integrated terminal. Try running `sudo kill` from another terminal which is not a Snap application, like Alacritty, gnome-terminal, Konsole, etc.

---

More info:

These types of containerized apps (Snap, Flatpak, etc.) are often restricted by [AppArmor](https://apparmor.net/) profiles which prevent certain system calls (also called "syscalls") from being made.

The `kill` command works by making a [`signal()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) syscall. If the `signal` syscall is blocked by the AppArmor profile applied to the terminal you are using, then this could result in permission denied.

You could check whether this is happening by checking the kernel logs (run the command `dmesg`). Example:

```
[ 6405.232002] audit: type=1400 audit(1658415742.446:231): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="docker-default" pid=89218 comm="kill" requested_mask="receive" denied_mask="receive" signal=kill peer="snap.code.code"
```

The key parts of the error message are: `apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" ... signal=kill`. This means that AppArmor is blocking the `signal` syscall which is attempting to kill the process.

Comment: This is really useful. I didn't know the VSCode terminal is containerized and it make sense, as there are some commands that refuse to work in the VSCode terminal, but work with no problem in the native terminal. `gitg` is an example of that. Very useful information!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with -9 switch? Since `sudo kill` sends -15 (SIGTERM) signal to process to kill itself. Process might not want to do that and therefore -9 (SIGKILL) is needed (if you can't find the underlying parent service to kill).

PS! -9 sends very bruteforce SIGKILL signal, so be careful, it will kill whatever is the underlying process and might result in unresponsive system.

Comment: do you mean sudo kill -s SIGKILL processID ? Permission denied as well. As for SIGTERM as well

Comment: `sudo -9 kill 2814` should work. Sometimes for reasons beyond my understanding some interactive shell processes might not respond to kill. Those cases either -9 signal or -HUP has helped `sudo kill -HUP 2814`. Sighup is an quite old signal for hang up and usually kills unresponsive processes or if daemon then reloads configurations. Just to clarify do you get "Permission denied" or "operation not permitted"?

Comment: `$ sudo kill -9 2993`

`kill: (2993): Permission denied`

`$ sudo kill -HUP 2993`

`kill: (2993): Permission denied`

`sudo -9 kill` was an error on your side right?

Sorry for poor formatting... Don'T know how to do it.

Comment: Yes, my typo. Let's take a look what `pstree -p` gives us about all those node processes. If you dont have it then package name is psmisc. Just copy the output or add it to you original question. Also use root terminal for this `sudo -i` for example will give u root terminal session.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help!
however, the process is finally terminated. Unfortunately, my whole laptop with it...
Well, it does not charge anymore:-/  So I cannot work with it anymore. However, If somebody else has the issue, we can hopefully find a solution.